# Program crashes when freeing pointer to array, why?

Tags: c, methods, numerical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this C-program correct(pointers and arrays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378404/is-this-c-program-correctpointers-and-arrays)

My program crashes when I free the mallocated array in the end. Why?
Also, I'm not 100% on how to allocate it in the first place. The program works as intended though, ecept for the crash when I free the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Approximates a solution to a differential equation on the form: 
   y'(t) + ay(t) = x(t)
   y(0) = b 
*/
double* runge_kutta_2nd_order(double stepSize, double a, double b, double (*x) (double), double upto)
{
    int resultSize = ((int) (upto / stepSize)) + 1;
    double yt = b;
    double time;
    double k1,k2,ystar1,ystar2;
    int index = 1;

    double *results = (double*) malloc(resultSize * (sizeof(double)));
    if(results == NULL)
        exit(0);

    results[0] = b;

    for(time = 0; time <= upto; time += stepSize)
    {
        k1 = x(time) - a * yt;
        ystar1 = yt + stepSize * k1;
        k2 = x(time + stepSize) - a * ystar1;
        ystar2 = yt + (k1 + k2) / 2 * stepSize;
        yt = ystar2;
        results[index] = ystar2;
        index++;
    }
    return results;
}

void free_results(double *r)
{
    free(r);
    r = NULL;
}


double insignal(double t)
{
    return exp(t/2)*(sin(5*t) - 10*cos(5*t));
}



int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double *res = runge_kutta_2nd_order(0.01,-1,0,&insignal,10);
    printf("\nRunge Kutta 2nd order approximation of the differential equation:");
    printf("\ny'(t) - y(t) = e^(t/2) * (sin(5t) - 10cos(5t))");
    printf("\ny(0) = 0");
    printf("\n0 <= t <= 10");

    for(i=0; i<1001; i++){
        printf("\ni = %lf => y = ", 0.01*i);
        printf("%lf", res[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free_results(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you allocate like this: `double *results = malloc(resultSize * sizeof(*results));` you don't need to write the type name all over.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't cast the pointer to double, does it?

Comment: You don't need to cast the pointer in C. The conversion is implicit.

Comment: ok, thanks. but do you know what goes wrong when i free the pointer?

Comment: When you free the data, you set the pointer `r` to `NULL`. This is only setting the pointer to `NULL` in that function. If you want to invalidate the pointer for the future, pass it as a pointer to a pointer (`double **r`) and use `free(*r)` and `*r = NULL*`. Call the function with `free_results(&res)`.

Comment: ok thanks, but i assume u mean *r=NULL; not *r = NULL*

Comment: Joachim's comment is correct with `*r = NULL`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378404/is-this-c-program-correctpointers-and-arrays

Answer (score 1):

You have a heap overflow in `runge_kutta_2nd_order`. Carefully check the loop to ensure that `index < resultSize` always holds.

Comment: thanks, fiex it now. i wrote outside the allocated array before.